# Trying to make plot look similar

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to get the following plot:

DESIRED:
[image]

I do not know what's going on with mine. Maybe there are some tweaks we can do to make it look similar to the desired one.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{color0}{RGB}{80,80,80}
\begin{axis}[
tick align=outside,
tick pos=left,
title={Ratings per items: Movielens 100K},
x grid style={white!69.01960784313725!black},
xlabel={Movies},
xmin=-84.05, xmax=1765.05,
xtick style={color=black},
y grid style={white!69.01960784313725!black},
ylabel={Number of Ratings},
ymin=-28.1, ymax=612.1,
ytick style={color=black}
]
\addplot [semithick, color0]
table {%
    0 583
    1 509
    2 508
    3 507
    4 485
    5 481
    6 478
    7 452
    8 431
    9 429
    10 420
    11 413
    12 394
    13 392
    14 390
    15 384
    16 378
    17 367
    18 365
    19 350
    20 350
    21 344
    22 336
    23 331
    24 326
    25 324
    26 321
    27 316
    28 316
    29 315
    30 303
    31 301
    32 300
    33 299
    34 298
    35 298
    36 297
    37 297
    38 295
    39 295
    40 293
    41 293
    42 293
    43 291
    44 290
    45 284
    46 283
    47 280
    48 280
    49 276
    50 276
    51 275
    52 272
    53 268
    54 267
    55 267
    56 264
    57 261
    58 259
    59 259
    60 256
    61 256
    62 255
    63 254
    64 251
    65 251
    66 251
    67 251
    68 250
    69 247
    70 246
    71 244
    72 244
    73 243
    74 243
    75 241
    76 240
    77 240
    78 239
    79 239
    80 236
    81 232
    82 231
    83 230
    84 230
    85 227
    86 227
    87 226
    88 223
    89 222
    90 221
    91 221
    92 221
    93 220
    94 220
    95 219
    96 219
    97 219
    98 219
    99 218
    100 217
    101 216
    102 215
    103 213
    104 212
    105 211
    106 209
    107 209
    108 209
    109 208
    110 208
    111 206
    112 206
    113 206
    114 202
    115 201
    116 201
    117 200
    118 199
    119 198
    120 198
    121 197
    122 195
    123 194
    124 194
    125 193
    126 192
    127 191
    128 190
    129 189
    130 188
    131 187
    132 185
    133 184
    134 183
    135 182
    136 182
    137 180
    138 180
    139 180
    140 179
    141 179
    142 179
    143 178
    144 178
    145 177
    146 176
    147 176
    148 175
    149 175
    150 175
    151 174
    152 174
    153 174
    154 173
    155 172
    156 172
    157 171
    158 171
    159 171
    160 171
    161 171
    162 171
    163 170
    164 170
    165 170
    166 170
    167 169
    168 169
    169 169
    170 168
    171 168
    172 166
    173 165
    174 164
    175 164
    176 164
    177 163
    178 162
    179 162
    180 162
    181 162
    182 162
    183 161
    184 160
    185 160
    186 160
    187 158
    188 158
    189 157
    190 157
    191 157
    192 156
    193 155
    194 154
    195 153
    196 153
    197 152
    198 151
    199 151
    200 151
    201 150
    202 150
    203 149
    204 149
    205 149
    206 148
    207 148
    208 148
    209 148
    210 147
    211 147
    212 146
    213 145
    214 145
    215 143
    216 143
    217 143
    218 142
    219 138
    220 138
    221 137
    222 137
    223 137
    224 137
    225 137
    226 137
    227 137
    228 136
    229 136
    230 136
    231 136
    232 134
    233 134
    234 134
    235 134
    236 133
    237 132
    238 131
    239 131
    240 130
    241 130
    242 129
    243 129
    244 129
    245 129
    246 128
    247 128
    248 128
    249 128
    250 128
    251 128
    252 128
    253 127
    254 127
    255 127
    256 127
    257 127
    258 127
    259 126
    260 126
    261 125
    262 125
    263 125
    264 125
    265 124
    266 124
    267 124
    268 124
    269 124
    270 124
    271 124
    272 123
    273 122
    274 121
    275 121
    276 121
    277 121
    278 121
    279 121
    280 120
    281 120
    282 120
    283 119
    284 119
    285 119
    286 118
    287 117
    288 117
    289 116
    290 116
    291 116
    292 116
    293 116
    294 115
    295 115
    296 115
    297 115
    298 114
    299 114
    300 114
    301 113
    302 112
    303 112
    304 112
    305 112
    306 111
    307 111
    308 110
    309 109
    310 108
    311 107
    312 106
    313 106
    314 106
    315 106
    316 105
    317 104
    318 104
    319 104
    320 104
    321 104
    322 103
    323 102
    324 102
    325 102
    326 102
    327 101
    328 101
    329 101
    330 101
    331 101
    332 101
    333 101
    334 100
    335 100
    336 100
    337 100
    338 99
    339 98
    340 98
    341 98
    342 97
    343 97
    344 97
    345 97
    346 96
    347 96
    348 96
    349 96
    350 95
    351 95
    352 95
    353 93
    354 93
    355 93
    356 93
    357 93
    358 93
    359 92
    360 92
    361 92
    362 92
    363 92
    364 92
    365 91
    366 91
    367 91
    368 91
    369 91
    370 91
    371 90
    372 90
    373 90
    374 90
    375 90
    376 89
    377 89
    378 89
    379 89
    380 89
    381 88
    382 87
    383 87
    384 87
    385 87
    386 87
    387 86
    388 86
    389 86
    390 86
    391 86
    392 86
    393 85
    394 85
    395 85
    396 85
    397 85
    398 84
    399 84
    400 83
    401 83
    402 82
    403 82
    404 82
    405 82
    406 82
    407 82
    408 82
    409 81
    410 81
    411 81
    412 81
    413 81
    414 81
    415 81
    416 80
    417 80
    418 80
    419 80
    420 80
    421 80
    422 79
    423 79
    424 79
    425 79
    426 79
    427 78
    428 78
    429 77
    430 77
    431 77
    432 77
    433 76
    434 76
    435 76
    436 75
    437 75
    438 75
    439 75
    440 74
    441 74
    442 74
    443 74
    444 73
    445 73
    446 73
    447 73
    448 73
    449 73
    450 72
    451 72
    452 72
    453 72
    454 72
    455 72
    456 71
    457 71
    458 71
    459 71
    460 71
    461 70
    462 70
    463 70
    464 70
    465 69
    466 69
    467 69
    468 69
    469 69
    470 69
    471 68
    472 68
    473 68
    474 68
    475 68
    476 68
    477 68
    478 67
    479 67
    480 67
    481 67
    482 67
    483 67
    484 67
    485 67
    486 67
    487 66
    488 66
    489 66
    490 66
    491 66
    492 66
    493 66
    494 66
    495 66
    496 66
    497 66
    498 66
    499 65
    500 65
    501 65
    502 65
    503 65
    504 65
    505 65
    506 65
    507 64
    508 64
    509 64
    510 64
    511 64
    512 64
    513 64
    514 64
    515 64
    516 64
    517 64
    518 64
    519 63
    520 63
    521 63
    522 63
    523 63
    524 63
    525 62
    526 62
    527 62
    528 62
    529 61
    530 61
    531 60
    532 60
    533 60
    534 60
    535 60
    536 59
    537 59
    538 59
    539 59
    540 59
    541 59
    542 59
    543 59
    544 59
    545 59
    546 58
    547 58
    548 58
    549 58
    550 58
    551 58
    552 58
    553 58
    554 57
    555 57
    556 57
    557 57
    558 57
    559 57
    560 57
    561 57
    562 57
    563 56
    564 56
    565 56
    566 55
    567 55
    568 55
    569 55
    570 54
    571 54
    572 54
    573 54
    574 54
    575 54
    576 53
    577 53
    578 53
    579 53
    580 53
    581 53
    582 53
    583 53
    584 52
    585 52
    586 52
    587 52
    588 52
    589 51
    590 51
    591 51
    592 51
    593 50
    594 50
    595 50
    596 50
    597 50
    598 50
    599 50
    600 50
    601 50
    602 50
    603 49
    604 49
    605 49
    606 49
    607 49
    608 49
    609 49
    610 49
    611 48
    612 48
    613 48
    614 48
    615 48
    616 48
    617 48
    618 48
    619 48
    620 47
    621 47
    622 47
    623 47
    624 47
    625 47
    626 47
    627 46
    628 46
    629 46
    630 46
    631 46
    632 46
    633 46
    634 46
    635 46
    636 46
    637 46
    638 46
    639 45
    640 45
    641 45
    642 45
    643 45
    644 45
    645 45
    646 45
    647 45
    648 45
    649 44
    650 44
    651 44
    652 44
    653 44
    654 44
    655 44
    656 44
    657 44
    658 44
    659 44
    660 44
    661 44
    662 44
    663 44
    664 44
    665 44
    666 43
    667 43
    668 43
    669 43
    670 43
    671 43
    672 43
    673 43
    674 43
    675 43
    676 43
    677 43
    678 42
    679 42
    680 42
    681 42
    682 42
    683 42
    684 42
    685 41
    686 41
    687 41
    688 41
    689 41
    690 41
    691 41
    692 41
    693 41
    694 41
    695 41
    696 40
    697 40
    698 40
    699 40
    700 40
    701 40
    702 40
    703 40
    704 40
    705 40
    706 40
    707 40
    708 39
    709 39
    710 39
    711 39
    712 39
    713 39
    714 39
    715 39
    716 39
    717 39
    718 39
    719 39
    720 39
    721 39
    722 39
    723 39
    724 38
    725 38
    726 38
    727 38
    728 38
    729 38
    730 38
    731 37
    732 37
    733 37
    734 37
    735 37
    736 37
    737 37
    738 37
    739 36
    740 36
    741 36
    742 36
    743 35
    744 35
    745 35
    746 35
    747 35
    748 35
    749 35
    750 34
    751 34
    752 34
    753 34
    754 34
    755 34
    756 34
    757 34
    758 34
    759 34
    760 34
    761 34
    762 33
    763 33
    764 33
    765 33
    766 33
    767 33
    768 33
    769 32
    770 32
    771 32
    772 32
    773 32
    774 32
    775 32
    776 32
    777 32
    778 32
    779 32
    780 32
    781 32
    782 32
    783 31
    784 31
    785 31
    786 31
    787 31
    788 31
    789 31
    790 31
    791 31
    792 31
    793 31
    794 31
    795 31
    796 31
    797 31
    798 30
    799 30
    800 30
    801 30
    802 30
    803 30
    804 30
    805 30
    806 29
    807 29
    808 29
    809 29
    810 29
    811 29
    812 29
    813 29
    814 29
    815 28
    816 28
    817 28
    818 28
    819 28
    820 28
    821 28
    822 28
    823 28
    824 28
    825 28
    826 28
    827 27
    828 27
    829 27
    830 27
    831 27
    832 27
    833 27
    834 27
    835 27
    836 27
    837 27
    838 27
    839 27
    840 27
    841 27
    842 27
    843 27
    844 26
    845 26
    846 26
    847 26
    848 26
    849 26
    850 26
    851 26
    852 26
    853 26
    854 26
    855 26
    856 26
    857 26
    858 25
    859 25
    860 25
    861 25
    862 25
    863 25
    864 25
    865 25
    866 25
    867 25
    868 25
    869 25
    870 25
    871 25
    872 24
    873 24
    874 24
    875 24
    876 24
    877 24
    878 24
    879 24
    880 24
    881 24
    882 24
    883 24
    884 23
    885 23
    886 23
    887 23
    888 23
    889 23
    890 23
    891 23
    892 23
    893 23
    894 23
    895 23
    896 22
    897 22
    898 22
    899 22
    900 22
    901 22
    902 22
    903 22
    904 22
    905 22
    906 22
    907 22
    908 22
    909 22
    910 22
    911 22
    912 22
    913 21
    914 21
    915 21
    916 21
    917 21
    918 21
    919 21
    920 21
    921 21
    922 21
    923 21
    924 21
    925 21
    926 21
    927 20
    928 20
    929 20
    930 20
    931 20
    932 20
    933 20
    934 20
    935 20
    936 20
    937 20
    938 20
    939 19
    940 19
    941 19
    942 19
    943 19
    944 19
    945 19
    946 19
    947 19
    948 19
    949 19
    950 19
    951 19
    952 19
    953 19
    954 19
    955 19
    956 19
    957 18
    958 18
    959 18
    960 18
    961 18
    962 18
    963 18
    964 18
    965 18
    966 18
    967 18
    968 18
    969 18
    970 18
    971 18
    972 18
    973 18
    974 18
    975 18
    976 18
    977 18
    978 18
    979 18
    980 18
    981 17
    982 17
    983 17
    984 17
    985 17
    986 17
    987 17
    988 17
    989 17
    990 17
    991 16
    992 16
    993 16
    994 16
    995 16
    996 16
    997 16
    998 16
    999 16
    1000 16
    1001 16
    1002 16
    1003 16
    1004 16
    1005 16
    1006 16
    1007 16
    1008 16
    1009 16
    1010 15
    1011 15
    1012 15
    1013 15
    1014 15
    1015 15
    1016 15
    1017 15
    1018 15
    1019 15
    1020 15
    1021 15
    1022 15
    1023 15
    1024 15
    1025 15
    1026 15
    1027 15
    1028 15
    1029 15
    1030 15
    1031 15
    1032 14
    1033 14
    1034 14
    1035 14
    1036 14
    1037 14
    1038 14
    1039 14
    1040 14
    1041 14
    1042 14
    1043 14
    1044 14
    1045 14
    1046 13
    1047 13
    1048 13
    1049 13
    1050 13
    1051 13
    1052 13
    1053 13
    1054 13
    1055 13
    1056 13
    1057 13
    1058 13
    1059 13
    1060 13
    1061 13
    1062 13
    1063 13
    1064 13
    1065 13
    1066 13
    1067 13
    1068 13
    1069 13
    1070 13
    1071 12
    1072 12
    1073 12
    1074 12
    1075 12
    1076 12
    1077 12
    1078 12
    1079 12
    1080 12
    1081 12
    1082 12
    1083 12
    1084 12
    1085 12
    1086 12
    1087 12
    1088 12
    1089 12
    1090 12
    1091 12
    1092 12
    1093 12
    1094 12
    1095 12
    1096 12
    1097 12
    1098 12
    1099 11
    1100 11
    1101 11
    1102 11
    1103 11
    1104 11
    1105 11
    1106 11
    1107 11
    1108 11
    1109 11
    1110 11
    1111 11
    1112 11
    1113 11
    1114 11
    1115 11
    1116 11
    1117 11
    1118 11
    1119 10
    1120 10
    1121 10
    1122 10
    1123 10
    1124 10
    1125 10
    1126 10
    1127 10
    1128 10
    1129 10
    1130 10
    1131 10
    1132 10
    1133 10
    1134 10
    1135 10
    1136 10
    1137 10
    1138 10
    1139 10
    1140 10
    1141 10
    1142 10
    1143 10
    1144 10
    1145 10
    1146 10
    1147 10
    1148 10
    1149 10
    1150 10
    1151 10
    1152 9
    1153 9
    1154 9
    1155 9
    1156 9
    1157 9
    1158 9
    1159 9
    1160 9
    1161 9
    1162 9
    1163 9
    1164 9
    1165 9
    1166 9
    1167 9
    1168 9
    1169 9
    1170 9
    1171 9
    1172 9
    1173 9
    1174 9
    1175 9
    1176 9
    1177 9
    1178 9
    1179 9
    1180 9
    1181 9
    1182 9
    1183 9
    1184 9
    1185 8
    1186 8
    1187 8
    1188 8
    1189 8
    1190 8
    1191 8
    1192 8
    1193 8
    1194 8
    1195 8
    1196 8
    1197 8
    1198 8
    1199 8
    1200 8
    1201 8
    1202 8
    1203 8
    1204 8
    1205 8
    1206 8
    1207 8
    1208 8
    1209 8
    1210 8
    1211 8
    1212 8
    1213 8
    1214 8
    1215 7
    1216 7
    1217 7
    1218 7
    1219 7
    1220 7
    1221 7
    1222 7
    1223 7
    1224 7
    1225 7
    1226 7
    1227 7
    1228 7
    1229 7
    1230 7
    1231 7
    1232 7
    1233 7
    1234 7
    1235 7
    1236 7
    1237 7
    1238 7
    1239 7
    1240 7
    1241 7
    1242 7
    1243 7
    1244 7
    1245 7
    1246 7
    1247 7
    1248 7
    1249 7
    1250 7
    1251 7
    1252 7
    1253 7
    1254 7
    1255 7
    1256 7
    1257 7
    1258 7
    1259 6
    1260 6
    1261 6
    1262 6
    1263 6
    1264 6
    1265 6
    1266 6
    1267 6
    1268 6
    1269 6
    1270 6
    1271 6
    1272 6
    1273 6
    1274 6
    1275 6
    1276 6
    1277 6
    1278 6
    1279 6
    1280 6
    1281 6
    1282 6
    1283 6
    1284 6
    1285 6
    1286 6
    1287 6
    1288 6
    1289 6
    1290 6
    1291 6
    1292 6
    1293 6
    1294 6
    1295 6
    1296 6
    1297 6
    1298 5
    1299 5
    1300 5
    1301 5
    1302 5
    1303 5
    1304 5
    1305 5
    1306 5
    1307 5
    1308 5
    1309 5
    1310 5
    1311 5
    1312 5
    1313 5
    1314 5
    1315 5
    1316 5
    1317 5
    1318 5
    1319 5
    1320 5
    1321 5
    1322 5
    1323 5
    1324 5
    1325 5
    1326 5
    1327 5
    1328 5
    1329 5
    1330 5
    1331 5
    1332 5
    1333 5
    1334 5
    1335 5
    1336 5
    1337 5
    1338 5
    1339 5
    1340 5
    1341 5
    1342 5
    1343 5
    1344 5
    1345 5
    1346 5
    1347 5
    1348 5
    1349 4
    1350 4
    1351 4
    1352 4
    1353 4
    1354 4
    1355 4
    1356 4
    1357 4
    1358 4
    1359 4
    1360 4
    1361 4
    1362 4
    1363 4
    1364 4
    1365 4
    1366 4
    1367 4
    1368 4
    1369 4
    1370 4
    1371 4
    1372 4
    1373 4
    1374 4
    1375 4
    1376 4
    1377 4
    1378 4
    1379 4
    1380 4
    1381 4
    1382 4
    1383 4
    1384 4
    1385 4
    1386 4
    1387 4
    1388 4
    1389 4
    1390 4
    1391 4
    1392 4
    1393 4
    1394 4
    1395 4
    1396 4
    1397 4
    1398 4
    1399 4
    1400 4
    1401 4
    1402 4
    1403 4
    1404 4
    1405 4
    1406 4
    1407 4
    1408 4
    1409 4
    1410 4
    1411 4
    1412 4
    1413 3
    1414 3
    1415 3
    1416 3
    1417 3
    1418 3
    1419 3
    1420 3
    1421 3
    1422 3
    1423 3
    1424 3
    1425 3
    1426 3
    1427 3
    1428 3
    1429 3
    1430 3
    1431 3
    1432 3
    1433 3
    1434 3
    1435 3
    1436 3
    1437 3
    1438 3
    1439 3
    1440 3
    1441 3
    1442 3
    1443 3
    1444 3
    1445 3
    1446 3
    1447 3
    1448 3
    1449 3
    1450 3
    1451 3
    1452 3
    1453 3
    1454 3
    1455 3
    1456 3
    1457 3
    1458 3
    1459 3
    1460 3
    1461 3
    1462 3
    1463 3
    1464 3
    1465 3
    1466 3
    1467 3
    1468 3
    1469 3
    1470 3
    1471 3
    1472 3
    1473 2
    1474 2
    1475 2
    1476 2
    1477 2
    1478 2
    1479 2
    1480 2
    1481 2
    1482 2
    1483 2
    1484 2
    1485 2
    1486 2
    1487 2
    1488 2
    1489 2
    1490 2
    1491 2
    1492 2
    1493 2
    1494 2
    1495 2
    1496 2
    1497 2
    1498 2
    1499 2
    1500 2
    1501 2
    1502 2
    1503 2
    1504 2
    1505 2
    1506 2
    1507 2
    1508 2
    1509 2
    1510 2
    1511 2
    1512 2
    1513 2
    1514 2
    1515 2
    1516 2
    1517 2
    1518 2
    1519 2
    1520 2
    1521 2
    1522 2
    1523 2
    1524 2
    1525 2
    1526 2
    1527 2
    1528 2
    1529 2
    1530 2
    1531 2
    1532 2
    1533 2
    1534 2
    1535 2
    1536 2
    1537 2
    1538 2
    1539 2
    1540 2
    1541 1
    1542 1
    1543 1
    1544 1
    1545 1
    1546 1
    1547 1
    1548 1
    1549 1
    1550 1
    1551 1
    1552 1
    1553 1
    1554 1
    1555 1
    1556 1
    1557 1
    1558 1
    1559 1
    1560 1
    1561 1
    1562 1
    1563 1
    1564 1
    1565 1
    1566 1
    1567 1
    1568 1
    1569 1
    1570 1
    1571 1
    1572 1
    1573 1
    1574 1
    1575 1
    1576 1
    1577 1
    1578 1
    1579 1
    1580 1
    1581 1
    1582 1
    1583 1
    1584 1
    1585 1
    1586 1
    1587 1
    1588 1
    1589 1
    1590 1
    1591 1
    1592 1
    1593 1
    1594 1
    1595 1
    1596 1
    1597 1
    1598 1
    1599 1
    1600 1
    1601 1
    1602 1
    1603 1
    1604 1
    1605 1
    1606 1
    1607 1
    1608 1
    1609 1
    1610 1
    1611 1
    1612 1
    1613 1
    1614 1
    1615 1
    1616 1
    1617 1
    1618 1
    1619 1
    1620 1
    1621 1
    1622 1
    1623 1
    1624 1
    1625 1
    1626 1
    1627 1
    1628 1
    1629 1
    1630 1
    1631 1
    1632 1
    1633 1
    1634 1
    1635 1
    1636 1
    1637 1
    1638 1
    1639 1
    1640 1
    1641 1
    1642 1
    1643 1
    1644 1
    1645 1
    1646 1
    1647 1
    1648 1
    1649 1
    1650 1
    1651 1
    1652 1
    1653 1
    1654 1
    1655 1
    1656 1
    1657 1
    1658 1
    1659 1
    1660 1
    1661 1
    1662 1
    1663 1
    1664 1
    1665 1
    1666 1
    1667 1
    1668 1
    1669 1
    1670 1
    1671 1
    1672 1
    1673 1
    1674 1
    1675 1
    1676 1
    1677 1
    1678 1
    1679 1
    1680 1
    1681 1
};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the graph more similar to the desired one, you could

1. Set the minimum values for `x` and `y` to zero
2. Fill the space between your graph and the horizontal axis

A possible solution which employs the `fillbetween` PGFPlots library:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{color0}{RGB}{80,80,80}
\begin{axis}[
tick align=outside,
tick pos=left,
title={Ratings per items: Movielens 100K},
x grid style={white!69.01960784313725!black},
xlabel={Movies},
xmin=0, xmax=1765.05,
xtick style={color=black},
y grid style={white!69.01960784313725!black},
ylabel={Number of Ratings},
ymin=0, ymax=612.1,
ytick style={color=black}
]
\addplot [name path=curve, semithick, color0]
table {%
    0 583
    1 509
    2 508
    3 507
    4 485
    5 481
    6 478
    7 452
    8 431
    9 429
    10 420
    11 413
    12 394
    13 392
    14 390
    15 384
    16 378
    17 367
    18 365
    19 350
    20 350
    21 344
    22 336
    23 331
    24 326
    25 324
    26 321
    27 316
    28 316
    29 315
    30 303
    31 301
    32 300
    33 299
    34 298
    35 298
    36 297
    37 297
    38 295
    39 295
    40 293
    41 293
    42 293
    43 291
    44 290
    45 284
    46 283
    47 280
    48 280
    49 276
    50 276
    51 275
    52 272
    53 268
    54 267
    55 267
    56 264
    57 261
    58 259
    59 259
    60 256
    61 256
    62 255
    63 254
    64 251
    65 251
    66 251
    67 251
    68 250
    69 247
    70 246
    71 244
    72 244
    73 243
    74 243
    75 241
    76 240
    77 240
    78 239
    79 239
    80 236
    81 232
    82 231
    83 230
    84 230
    85 227
    86 227
    87 226
    88 223
    89 222
    90 221
    91 221
    92 221
    93 220
    94 220
    95 219
    96 219
    97 219
    98 219
    99 218
    100 217
    101 216
    102 215
    103 213
    104 212
    105 211
    106 209
    107 209
    108 209
    109 208
    110 208
    111 206
    112 206
    113 206
    114 202
    115 201
    116 201
    117 200
    118 199
    119 198
    120 198
    121 197
    122 195
    123 194
    124 194
    125 193
    126 192
    127 191
    128 190
    129 189
    130 188
    131 187
    132 185
    133 184
    134 183
    135 182
    136 182
    137 180
    138 180
    139 180
    140 179
    141 179
    142 179
    143 178
    144 178
    145 177
    146 176
    147 176
    148 175
    149 175
    150 175
    151 174
    152 174
    153 174
    154 173
    155 172
    156 172
    157 171
    158 171
    159 171
    160 171
    161 171
    162 171
    163 170
    164 170
    165 170
    166 170
    167 169
    168 169
    169 169
    170 168
    171 168
    172 166
    173 165
    174 164
    175 164
    176 164
    177 163
    178 162
    179 162
    180 162
    181 162
    182 162
    183 161
    184 160
    185 160
    186 160
    187 158
    188 158
    189 157
    190 157
    191 157
    192 156
    193 155
    194 154
    195 153
    196 153
    197 152
    198 151
    199 151
    200 151
    201 150
    202 150
    203 149
    204 149
    205 149
    206 148
    207 148
    208 148
    209 148
    210 147
    211 147
    212 146
    213 145
    214 145
    215 143
    216 143
    217 143
    218 142
    219 138
    220 138
    221 137
    222 137
    223 137
    224 137
    225 137
    226 137
    227 137
    228 136
    229 136
    230 136
    231 136
    232 134
    233 134
    234 134
    235 134
    236 133
    237 132
    238 131
    239 131
    240 130
    241 130
    242 129
    243 129
    244 129
    245 129
    246 128
    247 128
    248 128
    249 128
    250 128
    251 128
    252 128
    253 127
    254 127
    255 127
    256 127
    257 127
    258 127
    259 126
    260 126
    261 125
    262 125
    263 125
    264 125
    265 124
    266 124
    267 124
    268 124
    269 124
    270 124
    271 124
    272 123
    273 122
    274 121
    275 121
    276 121
    277 121
    278 121
    279 121
    280 120
    281 120
    282 120
    283 119
    284 119
    285 119
    286 118
    287 117
    288 117
    289 116
    290 116
    291 116
    292 116
    293 116
    294 115
    295 115
    296 115
    297 115
    298 114
    299 114
    300 114
    301 113
    302 112
    303 112
    304 112
    305 112
    306 111
    307 111
    308 110
    309 109
    310 108
    311 107
    312 106
    313 106
    314 106
    315 106
    316 105
    317 104
    318 104
    319 104
    320 104
    321 104
    322 103
    323 102
    324 102
    325 102
    326 102
    327 101
    328 101
    329 101
    330 101
    331 101
    332 101
    333 101
    334 100
    335 100
    336 100
    337 100
    338 99
    339 98
    340 98
    341 98
    342 97
    343 97
    344 97
    345 97
    346 96
    347 96
    348 96
    349 96
    350 95
    351 95
    352 95
    353 93
    354 93
    355 93
    356 93
    357 93
    358 93
    359 92
    360 92
    361 92
    362 92
    363 92
    364 92
    365 91
    366 91
    367 91
    368 91
    369 91
    370 91
    371 90
    372 90
    373 90
    374 90
    375 90
    376 89
    377 89
    378 89
    379 89
    380 89
    381 88
    382 87
    383 87
    384 87
    385 87
    386 87
    387 86
    388 86
    389 86
    390 86
    391 86
    392 86
    393 85
    394 85
    395 85
    396 85
    397 85
    398 84
    399 84
    400 83
    401 83
    402 82
    403 82
    404 82
    405 82
    406 82
    407 82
    408 82
    409 81
    410 81
    411 81
    412 81
    413 81
    414 81
    415 81
    416 80
    417 80
    418 80
    419 80
    420 80
    421 80
    422 79
    423 79
    424 79
    425 79
    426 79
    427 78
    428 78
    429 77
    430 77
    431 77
    432 77
    433 76
    434 76
    435 76
    436 75
    437 75
    438 75
    439 75
    440 74
    441 74
    442 74
    443 74
    444 73
    445 73
    446 73
    447 73
    448 73
    449 73
    450 72
    451 72
    452 72
    453 72
    454 72
    455 72
    456 71
    457 71
    458 71
    459 71
    460 71
    461 70
    462 70
    463 70
    464 70
    465 69
    466 69
    467 69
    468 69
    469 69
    470 69
    471 68
    472 68
    473 68
    474 68
    475 68
    476 68
    477 68
    478 67
    479 67
    480 67
    481 67
    482 67
    483 67
    484 67
    485 67
    486 67
    487 66
    488 66
    489 66
    490 66
    491 66
    492 66
    493 66
    494 66
    495 66
    496 66
    497 66
    498 66
    499 65
    500 65
    501 65
    502 65
    503 65
    504 65
    505 65
    506 65
    507 64
    508 64
    509 64
    510 64
    511 64
    512 64
    513 64
    514 64
    515 64
    516 64
    517 64
    518 64
    519 63
    520 63
    521 63
    522 63
    523 63
    524 63
    525 62
    526 62
    527 62
    528 62
    529 61
    530 61
    531 60
    532 60
    533 60
    534 60
    535 60
    536 59
    537 59
    538 59
    539 59
    540 59
    541 59
    542 59
    543 59
    544 59
    545 59
    546 58
    547 58
    548 58
    549 58
    550 58
    551 58
    552 58
    553 58
    554 57
    555 57
    556 57
    557 57
    558 57
    559 57
    560 57
    561 57
    562 57
    563 56
    564 56
    565 56
    566 55
    567 55
    568 55
    569 55
    570 54
    571 54
    572 54
    573 54
    574 54
    575 54
    576 53
    577 53
    578 53
    579 53
    580 53
    581 53
    582 53
    583 53
    584 52
    585 52
    586 52
    587 52
    588 52
    589 51
    590 51
    591 51
    592 51
    593 50
    594 50
    595 50
    596 50
    597 50
    598 50
    599 50
    600 50
    601 50
    602 50
    603 49
    604 49
    605 49
    606 49
    607 49
    608 49
    609 49
    610 49
    611 48
    612 48
    613 48
    614 48
    615 48
    616 48
    617 48
    618 48
    619 48
    620 47
    621 47
    622 47
    623 47
    624 47
    625 47
    626 47
    627 46
    628 46
    629 46
    630 46
    631 46
    632 46
    633 46
    634 46
    635 46
    636 46
    637 46
    638 46
    639 45
    640 45
    641 45
    642 45
    643 45
    644 45
    645 45
    646 45
    647 45
    648 45
    649 44
    650 44
    651 44
    652 44
    653 44
    654 44
    655 44
    656 44
    657 44
    658 44
    659 44
    660 44
    661 44
    662 44
    663 44
    664 44
    665 44
    666 43
    667 43
    668 43
    669 43
    670 43
    671 43
    672 43
    673 43
    674 43
    675 43
    676 43
    677 43
    678 42
    679 42
    680 42
    681 42
    682 42
    683 42
    684 42
    685 41
    686 41
    687 41
    688 41
    689 41
    690 41
    691 41
    692 41
    693 41
    694 41
    695 41
    696 40
    697 40
    698 40
    699 40
    700 40
    701 40
    702 40
    703 40
    704 40
    705 40
    706 40
    707 40
    708 39
    709 39
    710 39
    711 39
    712 39
    713 39
    714 39
    715 39
    716 39
    717 39
    718 39
    719 39
    720 39
    721 39
    722 39
    723 39
    724 38
    725 38
    726 38
    727 38
    728 38
    729 38
    730 38
    731 37
    732 37
    733 37
    734 37
    735 37
    736 37
    737 37
    738 37
    739 36
    740 36
    741 36
    742 36
    743 35
    744 35
    745 35
    746 35
    747 35
    748 35
    749 35
    750 34
    751 34
    752 34
    753 34
    754 34
    755 34
    756 34
    757 34
    758 34
    759 34
    760 34
    761 34
    762 33
    763 33
    764 33
    765 33
    766 33
    767 33
    768 33
    769 32
    770 32
    771 32
    772 32
    773 32
    774 32
    775 32
    776 32
    777 32
    778 32
    779 32
    780 32
    781 32
    782 32
    783 31
    784 31
    785 31
    786 31
    787 31
    788 31
    789 31
    790 31
    791 31
    792 31
    793 31
    794 31
    795 31
    796 31
    797 31
    798 30
    799 30
    800 30
    801 30
    802 30
    803 30
    804 30
    805 30
    806 29
    807 29
    808 29
    809 29
    810 29
    811 29
    812 29
    813 29
    814 29
    815 28
    816 28
    817 28
    818 28
    819 28
    820 28
    821 28
    822 28
    823 28
    824 28
    825 28
    826 28
    827 27
    828 27
    829 27
    830 27
    831 27
    832 27
    833 27
    834 27
    835 27
    836 27
    837 27
    838 27
    839 27
    840 27
    841 27
    842 27
    843 27
    844 26
    845 26
    846 26
    847 26
    848 26
    849 26
    850 26
    851 26
    852 26
    853 26
    854 26
    855 26
    856 26
    857 26
    858 25
    859 25
    860 25
    861 25
    862 25
    863 25
    864 25
    865 25
    866 25
    867 25
    868 25
    869 25
    870 25
    871 25
    872 24
    873 24
    874 24
    875 24
    876 24
    877 24
    878 24
    879 24
    880 24
    881 24
    882 24
    883 24
    884 23
    885 23
    886 23
    887 23
    888 23
    889 23
    890 23
    891 23
    892 23
    893 23
    894 23
    895 23
    896 22
    897 22
    898 22
    899 22
    900 22
    901 22
    902 22
    903 22
    904 22
    905 22
    906 22
    907 22
    908 22
    909 22
    910 22
    911 22
    912 22
    913 21
    914 21
    915 21
    916 21
    917 21
    918 21
    919 21
    920 21
    921 21
    922 21
    923 21
    924 21
    925 21
    926 21
    927 20
    928 20
    929 20
    930 20
    931 20
    932 20
    933 20
    934 20
    935 20
    936 20
    937 20
    938 20
    939 19
    940 19
    941 19
    942 19
    943 19
    944 19
    945 19
    946 19
    947 19
    948 19
    949 19
    950 19
    951 19
    952 19
    953 19
    954 19
    955 19
    956 19
    957 18
    958 18
    959 18
    960 18
    961 18
    962 18
    963 18
    964 18
    965 18
    966 18
    967 18
    968 18
    969 18
    970 18
    971 18
    972 18
    973 18
    974 18
    975 18
    976 18
    977 18
    978 18
    979 18
    980 18
    981 17
    982 17
    983 17
    984 17
    985 17
    986 17
    987 17
    988 17
    989 17
    990 17
    991 16
    992 16
    993 16
    994 16
    995 16
    996 16
    997 16
    998 16
    999 16
    1000 16
    1001 16
    1002 16
    1003 16
    1004 16
    1005 16
    1006 16
    1007 16
    1008 16
    1009 16
    1010 15
    1011 15
    1012 15
    1013 15
    1014 15
    1015 15
    1016 15
    1017 15
    1018 15
    1019 15
    1020 15
    1021 15
    1022 15
    1023 15
    1024 15
    1025 15
    1026 15
    1027 15
    1028 15
    1029 15
    1030 15
    1031 15
    1032 14
    1033 14
    1034 14
    1035 14
    1036 14
    1037 14
    1038 14
    1039 14
    1040 14
    1041 14
    1042 14
    1043 14
    1044 14
    1045 14
    1046 13
    1047 13
    1048 13
    1049 13
    1050 13
    1051 13
    1052 13
    1053 13
    1054 13
    1055 13
    1056 13
    1057 13
    1058 13
    1059 13
    1060 13
    1061 13
    1062 13
    1063 13
    1064 13
    1065 13
    1066 13
    1067 13
    1068 13
    1069 13
    1070 13
    1071 12
    1072 12
    1073 12
    1074 12
    1075 12
    1076 12
    1077 12
    1078 12
    1079 12
    1080 12
    1081 12
    1082 12
    1083 12
    1084 12
    1085 12
    1086 12
    1087 12
    1088 12
    1089 12
    1090 12
    1091 12
    1092 12
    1093 12
    1094 12
    1095 12
    1096 12
    1097 12
    1098 12
    1099 11
    1100 11
    1101 11
    1102 11
    1103 11
    1104 11
    1105 11
    1106 11
    1107 11
    1108 11
    1109 11
    1110 11
    1111 11
    1112 11
    1113 11
    1114 11
    1115 11
    1116 11
    1117 11
    1118 11
    1119 10
    1120 10
    1121 10
    1122 10
    1123 10
    1124 10
    1125 10
    1126 10
    1127 10
    1128 10
    1129 10
    1130 10
    1131 10
    1132 10
    1133 10
    1134 10
    1135 10
    1136 10
    1137 10
    1138 10
    1139 10
    1140 10
    1141 10
    1142 10
    1143 10
    1144 10
    1145 10
    1146 10
    1147 10
    1148 10
    1149 10
    1150 10
    1151 10
    1152 9
    1153 9
    1154 9
    1155 9
    1156 9
    1157 9
    1158 9
    1159 9
    1160 9
    1161 9
    1162 9
    1163 9
    1164 9
    1165 9
    1166 9
    1167 9
    1168 9
    1169 9
    1170 9
    1171 9
    1172 9
    1173 9
    1174 9
    1175 9
    1176 9
    1177 9
    1178 9
    1179 9
    1180 9
    1181 9
    1182 9
    1183 9
    1184 9
    1185 8
    1186 8
    1187 8
    1188 8
    1189 8
    1190 8
    1191 8
    1192 8
    1193 8
    1194 8
    1195 8
    1196 8
    1197 8
    1198 8
    1199 8
    1200 8
    1201 8
    1202 8
    1203 8
    1204 8
    1205 8
    1206 8
    1207 8
    1208 8
    1209 8
    1210 8
    1211 8
    1212 8
    1213 8
    1214 8
    1215 7
    1216 7
    1217 7
    1218 7
    1219 7
    1220 7
    1221 7
    1222 7
    1223 7
    1224 7
    1225 7
    1226 7
    1227 7
    1228 7
    1229 7
    1230 7
    1231 7
    1232 7
    1233 7
    1234 7
    1235 7
    1236 7
    1237 7
    1238 7
    1239 7
    1240 7
    1241 7
    1242 7
    1243 7
    1244 7
    1245 7
    1246 7
    1247 7
    1248 7
    1249 7
    1250 7
    1251 7
    1252 7
    1253 7
    1254 7
    1255 7
    1256 7
    1257 7
    1258 7
    1259 6
    1260 6
    1261 6
    1262 6
    1263 6
    1264 6
    1265 6
    1266 6
    1267 6
    1268 6
    1269 6
    1270 6
    1271 6
    1272 6
    1273 6
    1274 6
    1275 6
    1276 6
    1277 6
    1278 6
    1279 6
    1280 6
    1281 6
    1282 6
    1283 6
    1284 6
    1285 6
    1286 6
    1287 6
    1288 6
    1289 6
    1290 6
    1291 6
    1292 6
    1293 6
    1294 6
    1295 6
    1296 6
    1297 6
    1298 5
    1299 5
    1300 5
    1301 5
    1302 5
    1303 5
    1304 5
    1305 5
    1306 5
    1307 5
    1308 5
    1309 5
    1310 5
    1311 5
    1312 5
    1313 5
    1314 5
    1315 5
    1316 5
    1317 5
    1318 5
    1319 5
    1320 5
    1321 5
    1322 5
    1323 5
    1324 5
    1325 5
    1326 5
    1327 5
    1328 5
    1329 5
    1330 5
    1331 5
    1332 5
    1333 5
    1334 5
    1335 5
    1336 5
    1337 5
    1338 5
    1339 5
    1340 5
    1341 5
    1342 5
    1343 5
    1344 5
    1345 5
    1346 5
    1347 5
    1348 5
    1349 4
    1350 4
    1351 4
    1352 4
    1353 4
    1354 4
    1355 4
    1356 4
    1357 4
    1358 4
    1359 4
    1360 4
    1361 4
    1362 4
    1363 4
    1364 4
    1365 4
    1366 4
    1367 4
    1368 4
    1369 4
    1370 4
    1371 4
    1372 4
    1373 4
    1374 4
    1375 4
    1376 4
    1377 4
    1378 4
    1379 4
    1380 4
    1381 4
    1382 4
    1383 4
    1384 4
    1385 4
    1386 4
    1387 4
    1388 4
    1389 4
    1390 4
    1391 4
    1392 4
    1393 4
    1394 4
    1395 4
    1396 4
    1397 4
    1398 4
    1399 4
    1400 4
    1401 4
    1402 4
    1403 4
    1404 4
    1405 4
    1406 4
    1407 4
    1408 4
    1409 4
    1410 4
    1411 4
    1412 4
    1413 3
    1414 3
    1415 3
    1416 3
    1417 3
    1418 3
    1419 3
    1420 3
    1421 3
    1422 3
    1423 3
    1424 3
    1425 3
    1426 3
    1427 3
    1428 3
    1429 3
    1430 3
    1431 3
    1432 3
    1433 3
    1434 3
    1435 3
    1436 3
    1437 3
    1438 3
    1439 3
    1440 3
    1441 3
    1442 3
    1443 3
    1444 3
    1445 3
    1446 3
    1447 3
    1448 3
    1449 3
    1450 3
    1451 3
    1452 3
    1453 3
    1454 3
    1455 3
    1456 3
    1457 3
    1458 3
    1459 3
    1460 3
    1461 3
    1462 3
    1463 3
    1464 3
    1465 3
    1466 3
    1467 3
    1468 3
    1469 3
    1470 3
    1471 3
    1472 3
    1473 2
    1474 2
    1475 2
    1476 2
    1477 2
    1478 2
    1479 2
    1480 2
    1481 2
    1482 2
    1483 2
    1484 2
    1485 2
    1486 2
    1487 2
    1488 2
    1489 2
    1490 2
    1491 2
    1492 2
    1493 2
    1494 2
    1495 2
    1496 2
    1497 2
    1498 2
    1499 2
    1500 2
    1501 2
    1502 2
    1503 2
    1504 2
    1505 2
    1506 2
    1507 2
    1508 2
    1509 2
    1510 2
    1511 2
    1512 2
    1513 2
    1514 2
    1515 2
    1516 2
    1517 2
    1518 2
    1519 2
    1520 2
    1521 2
    1522 2
    1523 2
    1524 2
    1525 2
    1526 2
    1527 2
    1528 2
    1529 2
    1530 2
    1531 2
    1532 2
    1533 2
    1534 2
    1535 2
    1536 2
    1537 2
    1538 2
    1539 2
    1540 2
    1541 1
    1542 1
    1543 1
    1544 1
    1545 1
    1546 1
    1547 1
    1548 1
    1549 1
    1550 1
    1551 1
    1552 1
    1553 1
    1554 1
    1555 1
    1556 1
    1557 1
    1558 1
    1559 1
    1560 1
    1561 1
    1562 1
    1563 1
    1564 1
    1565 1
    1566 1
    1567 1
    1568 1
    1569 1
    1570 1
    1571 1
    1572 1
    1573 1
    1574 1
    1575 1
    1576 1
    1577 1
    1578 1
    1579 1
    1580 1
    1581 1
    1582 1
    1583 1
    1584 1
    1585 1
    1586 1
    1587 1
    1588 1
    1589 1
    1590 1
    1591 1
    1592 1
    1593 1
    1594 1
    1595 1
    1596 1
    1597 1
    1598 1
    1599 1
    1600 1
    1601 1
    1602 1
    1603 1
    1604 1
    1605 1
    1606 1
    1607 1
    1608 1
    1609 1
    1610 1
    1611 1
    1612 1
    1613 1
    1614 1
    1615 1
    1616 1
    1617 1
    1618 1
    1619 1
    1620 1
    1621 1
    1622 1
    1623 1
    1624 1
    1625 1
    1626 1
    1627 1
    1628 1
    1629 1
    1630 1
    1631 1
    1632 1
    1633 1
    1634 1
    1635 1
    1636 1
    1637 1
    1638 1
    1639 1
    1640 1
    1641 1
    1642 1
    1643 1
    1644 1
    1645 1
    1646 1
    1647 1
    1648 1
    1649 1
    1650 1
    1651 1
    1652 1
    1653 1
    1654 1
    1655 1
    1656 1
    1657 1
    1658 1
    1659 1
    1660 1
    1661 1
    1662 1
    1663 1
    1664 1
    1665 1
    1666 1
    1667 1
    1668 1
    1669 1
    1670 1
    1671 1
    1672 1
    1673 1
    1674 1
    1675 1
    1676 1
    1677 1
    1678 1
    1679 1
    1680 1
    1681 1
};
\path[name path=axis] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:1681,0);
\addplot fill between [of=curve and axis];
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output:
[image]

Comment: NICE! How do you change the color of the area below the curve?

Comment: Just use `\addplot[blue] fill between [of=curve and axis];` in the last line for example.